# ДиректорА или директорЫ?

Tags: орфоэпия

Какое окончание и ударения правильно для русского языка: "директорА" или "директорЫ"? И как быть с другими подобными словами "учителя - учители", "крема-кремы" и т.д.?

Comment: Да, грань применения того или иного окончания весьма тонка. Она где-то в области эстетики. Но... когда читаю "наши сервера" - мозг сносит. Вроде как нет сервера...
На рекламе сплошь и рядом "скуттера" - ну почему не написать скуттеры? Или вот "Наши автора" - вообще охренеть можно. И это торочат люди, претендующие на публичность и компетенцию в медиа....

Comment: я бы предложил окончание "ы" для объектов из мира идей. Тогда удилА. А если подразумеваются чертежи, то удИлы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально правильной формой для русского языка было, однозначно, "директоры". "Директора" (наряду с другими аналогичными словами: "слесаря", "шофера", "чучелА", "удилА" и т.д.) являются профессиональными сленговыми словами. Однако сейчас они все больше и больше стали входить в русскую речь.
В данном случае нет единого правила, и человеку решать самому, какую форму употреблять. Что же до множественного числа от слова "крем", то тут, однозначно, "кремы". "КремА" - это крайне награмотно.

Comment: ДиректорА - форма совсем не только профессиональная, она давно стало общелитературной. Выбирать здесь не приходится.

Answer (score 4):

Именительный падеж множественного числа — директорА. Это не неологизм (так — даже в давным-давно изданном словаре Ушакова). Неграмотно (Вы уж простите, Fuchoin Kazuki) — *халуи* вместо *холуи*.

УчителЯ — преподаватели; учИтели — главы учений, имеющие последователей.

КрЕмы.

"И т. д." - здесь: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=plural

Answer (score 2):

Мне "директоры" режут слух куда больше, чем "шофера". Там хотя бы профсленг, а "директоры" - вообще ниоткуда. И все-таки "закусить удила", а не "закусить удилы". Такой он, русский язык. Проверяйте грамотность.

Comment: Удила - это от удило, средний род. Окончание -А во множественном характерно для одно-двусложных существительных М.р., преимущественно на -р, реже - с суффиксом -ель (т.е. обозначающих профессию или инструмент). Удила - никаким боком.

Answer (score 2):

"Словарь трудностей русского языка". - М., Русский язык, 1985, с. 159:

"Директор, мн. директор**а** (не директоры)".

Answer (score 1):

Именительный падеж единственного числа - "директор", именительный множественного - "директорА". Эту форму, только эту, приводят в качестве единственно правильной все современные словари! Приехали директорА крупных заводов, собрались директорА, у них сегодня совет директорОв, мы написали письмо директорАм... Так, только так. В этом и сомневаться не стоит.

Comment: Мне эти всякие "директора", "шофера" и "слесаря" ОЧЕНЬ режут слух как неологизм и неграмотность. Как и всякие "в этой связи", "коммунизЬм" и всякие словечки, которые наши халую любят повторять за руководителями.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд должно быть либо оба варианта, либо "директорЫ" потому что: ректорЫ, лекторЫ и должно быть инмпекторЫ , а не инспекторА и архитекторЫ и т.д.